# Xcode Simulator - Show White Devices Instead of Black

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

When I run Xcode Simulator the devices are simulated with black cases. I'd like to be able to toggle to show devices with white cases to see them easier. I don't see a setting in Xcode for that. Can it be done?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @BartoszWoźniak I haven't heard from anyone, but it doesn't look like there's an option to change the device color.